# Need to check history for duplicates and then remove them

Tags: javascript

So my problem is that when a video is watched it adds to the history, but the problem is that video if watched multiple times appears multiple times too.

Here is the code:

```
function watch(video) {

    document.location.hash = video["id"];
    updateHistory(video);

    $("#shareitlink").val(document.location.href);

    var html = "<b>{0}</b><br>by {1}<br>{2} | {3} views";
    $("#videoInfo").html(html.format(video["title"], video["uploader"], video["length"], video["views"]));


    ytplayer.loadVideoById(video["id"]);


    getRelated(video["id"], true);
    return false;
    }

    function watchHistoricVideo(videoID) {
    $.each(myhistory, function(key, val) {
        if (val["id"] === videoID) {
            watch(val);
            return false;
        }
    });
    }

    function updateHistory(video) {
    blacklist[video["id"]] = true;
    myhistory.push(video);
    var html = "<li class=\"history\">" +
               "<img class= \"img-rounded\" src=\"{0}\"/>" +
               "<p><b title=\"{2}\"><a class=\"extendedLink\" href=\"javascript:watchHistoricVideo(\'{1}\');\"><span></span>{2}</a></b><br>" +
               "by {3}<br>" +
               "{4} | {5} views</p>" +
               "</li>";

    $("#myhistory").prepend(html.format(video["thumbnail"],
                                           video["id"],
                                           video["title"],
                                           video["uploader"],
                                           video["length"],
                                           video["views"]));

    }
```

I've tried using arrays and such but not really sure what I'm doing (I'm new to javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if the video is already in the history, then it should not be added? Or should the video be added to the history if it was not the last one played (even if it was in the history previously)?

**Scenario 1: New Video is in the history anywhere:**

**Change:**

```
document.location.hash = video["id"];
updateHistory(video);
```

**To:**

```
if ($.grep(myhistory, function (item) { return item["id"] == video["id"]; }).length == 0) {
    document.location.hash = video["id"];
    updateHistory(video);
}
```

**Scenario 2: New Video is just the last-viewed video:**

**Change:**

```
document.location.hash = video["id"];
updateHistory(video);
```

**To:**

```
if (myhistory[myhistory.length - 1]["id"] != video["id"]) {
    document.location.hash = video["id"];
    updateHistory(video);
}
```